# Understanding htop core percentage usage vs the task running

Tags: centos7, htop

I have a dual processor system 10 cores 2 threads per core
So this is 40 cores

In the image below you can see that in the Task it says that only 3 are running however I can see usage on 26 of them

I do not understand this

[image: picture of cores]